# Mathematically sum a sequence

Tags: python, math

I'm lacking of fundamental maths, and was wondering if there is a more efficient approach than looping for this algorithm:

```py
dt = 1 / 60.
vel = 1000.
fri = 0.05
result = 0
while vel > 0.5:
    vel -= vel * fri
    result += vel * dt
print(result)
```

Edit: you can see an example of vel and result over each iteration here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1dfvxzgxvt

Comment: This seems to be an Euler algorithm for numerically solving a differential equation. So do you need the other approach to give the same answer or would an approximation suffice?

Comment: Inspired by @RoryDaulton: If the problem needs a better quality solution, check (maybe) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlet_integration#Velocity_Verlet

Comment: An approximation suffice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the lower limit on `vel` is just to make the iteration stop some time.

Then what you are doing is calculating an infinite so-called geometric series

```
k+k^2+k^3+k^4+...
```

where `k` = `1-fri` = 0.95

The result is `k/(1-k)` = 19. I left out the start value of `vel` and `dt` because they are just multiplicative constants. The final result is 19*1000/60 = 316.66667.

Comment: Another algorithm was proposed from inclement, i compiled the 3 answers in python code here: https://gist.github.com/tito/a4b9a7a0016ad3b596b6881c753bfd28

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want the answer after infinite time then Arndt Jonasson has the answer.

## Speed up the code

Alternatively, if you simply want to speed the existing code up then `numba` can be very handy for this numeric sort of code:

```
def fn():
    dt = 1 / 60.
    vel = 1000.
    fri = 0.05
    result = 0
    while vel > 0.5:
        vel -= vel * fri
        result += vel * dt
    return result

from numba import njit
numba_fn = njit(fn)
```

If we time the two we see a big difference:

```
%timeit fn()
10.2 µs ± 12.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit numba_fn()
429 ns ± 5.86 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

## Integrate to get distance at any time

Finally, if you want to solve this problem generally for any finite time, then integration is your friend. The algorithm you show is described by the following equation

```
dv / dt = - 60 fri v(t)
```

In other words, the change in velocity is proportional to the velocity (60 is just a factor coming from the original time step). This is known as a first order differential equation and has the solution

```
from math import exp

def v(t):
    """Velocity at time ``t``.
    """
    return 950 * exp(-fri * 60 * t)
```

where 950 is the initial velocity (not 1000 as you change it before 'moving'), so we compute the time the velocity reaches 0.5 by solving the above equation for v(t) = 0.5:

```
from math import log
tf = log(0.5 / 1000) / (-fri * 60)  # approx(2.53)
```

Then to get the distance traveled until time `tf` we integrate `v(t)` from `0` to `tf`:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
distance, err = quad(v, 0, tf)
print(distance)
316.50833333333327
```

Or to confirm the infinite time answer:

```
import numpy as np
print(quad(v, 0, np.inf)[0])

316.6666666666584
```